# Mazda rd 8 2005

Tags: mazda, wiring, fan

Ok I need help I’m trying to connect my AC fan and my coolant fan back to original connection I had disconnected and had rigged to where when I started the vehicle it would start the fans now I fixed my vehicle. So now I need to connect both fans back to the original conectiksn but I don’t remember exactly what color goes with what. I have 4 wires black, red, green and blue

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I think we're going to need some more information from you as well as some pictures if you have them. What did you modify to make them instant on with the ignition? I realize you cut wires (or assume you did?), but I don't understand how you did that in the first place? Did you wire them directly into a power source? Did you wire them to the fuse box? Maybe if you enlightened us with a little more detail we'd be able to help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.